# Interchanging limit and infinite product in Euler product for Dedekind function s=1

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, limits-and-convergence, zeta-functions, euler-product

For an quartic (non-Galois) CM-field $K$ I have factors $v_p$ and for every prime $p$ found the following relation
$$v_p={\frac  {\prod_{\mathfrak{p}|p;\mathfrak{p}\subset\mathcal0_{K}}(1-N_{{K/{\mathbf  {Q}}}}(P))^{{-1}})}{\prod_{\mathfrak{p}|p;\mathfrak{p}\subset\mathcal0_{K_+}}(1-N_{{K_+/{\mathbf  {Q}}}}(P)^{{-1}})}}$$

I want to relate these factors to the relative class number of $K$ over its maximal totally real subfield $K_+$, using the analytic class number formula.

Jet to do this I have to change a infinite product and a limit. So my question is, can I do the following?

$$\prod_{p\text{ prime}} v_p=\prod_{p\text{ prime}}{\lim_{s\to 1}\frac  {\prod_{\mathfrak{p}|p;\mathfrak{p}\subset\mathcal0_{K}}(1-(N_{{K/{\mathbf  {Q}}}}(P))^{{-s}})}{\prod_{\mathfrak{p}|p;\mathfrak{p}\subset\mathcal0_{K_+}}(1-(N_{{K_+/{\mathbf  {Q}}}}(P))^{{-s}})}}\\\phantom{=\lim_{s\to1}\frac{\zeta_K(s)}{\zeta_{K_+}(s)}\prod_{p\text{ prime}} v_p}\overset?=\lim_{s\to 1}{\prod_{p\text{ prime}}{\frac  {\prod_{\mathfrak{p}|p;\mathfrak{p}\subset\mathcal0_{K}}(1-(N_{{K/{\mathbf  {Q}}}}(P))^{{-s}})}{\prod_{\mathfrak{p}|p;\mathfrak{p}\subset\mathcal0_{K_+}}(1-(N_{{K_+/{\mathbf  {Q}}}}(P))^{{-s}})}}}=\lim_{s\to1}\frac{\zeta_K(s)}{\zeta_{K_+}(s)}$$

Comment: Yes the Euler product of $\frac{\zeta_K(s)}{\zeta_{\mathbf{Q}}(s)}$ and hence of $\frac{\zeta_K(s)}{\zeta_{K^+}(s)}$ converges for $\Re(s) = 1$, this is equivalent to the prime number theorem for those zeta functions and for Artin L-functions of the Galois closure, from which the Chebotarev density theorem is obtained

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I thought to change the limits $\lim_{N\to \infty}\prod_{p<N}$ and $\lim_{s\to1}$ that the product has to converges absolutely and this converges conditionally if I am not mistaken.

Comment: If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ converges then $\lim_{s \to 0, \Re(s) > 0, |Im(s)| < \Re(s)} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$. Taking the logarithm, it works the same way for your products. Here $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-it}$ converges for every $t$ and to a continuous function of $t$, and hence $\lim_{s \to it, \Re(s) > 0} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-it}$

Comment: Dear reuns, thanks for the help. Can you help me with a reference for this fact?

Comment: A reference for what part ? For your statement, a proof of the prime number theorem for $\zeta_K$, $K/ \mathbb{Q}$ might suffice. My last comment is elementary from summation by parts.

Comment: See [Neukrich's](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Algebraic%20Number%20Theory%20-%20Neukrich.pdf) book